# the command grep "$SHELL$" foo

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I am having trouble understanding what this command does and more importantly the significance of both the $s in the command. I started by making a file foo and filled it with words like SHELL, WELL, etc. I then tried the command, however it did not print anything, so I thought that maybe something was wrong with my terminal. See my terminal below:

```
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2 (cs3300-301722)$ cat foo
SHELL
HELL
WELL
SHELL
SWELL
DWELL
FAREWELL
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2 (cs3300-301722)$ grep "$SHELL$" foo
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2 (cs3300-301722)$
```

I then decided to play around with the command by first trying it without the first $ and then doing the same thing except without the second $. My results are below:

```
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2 (cs3300-301722)$ grep "$SHELL" foo
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2 (cs3300-301722)$ grep "SHELL$" foo
SHELL
SHELL
```

I got some results but I am still confused as to what each $ does and why the command does not work with both in place. Can someone explain?

Comment: Basically `grep "$SHELL" foo` doesn't work because `$SHELL` is expanded to your SHELL environment variable by bash (try `echo $SHELL` to see for yourself). As mentioned in @knittl's answer, `$` is also a regular expression pattern meaning to match the end of line. Since `SHELL$` isn't expanded by bash it is passed along to grep, which matches any line that ends with `SHELL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$SHELL` expands](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_03) to the path of your currently executing shell. `$` without text after it does not expand and stays unaltered.

If executed in the Bash shell, your final command would look like:

```
grep '/bin/bash$' foo
```

`$` as part of a [regular-expression](/questions/tagged/regular-expression) – which is what a [`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) [pattern](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) is – means "end of line".

You can verify it by prepending your command with `echo`, or enabling command tracing in your shell: [`set -x`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25)

All that said, using `$` unescaped and expecting it to not expand is bad practice (in other words: waiting for surprising stuff to happen). Better to be explicit where you want shell expansion to be performed and where not:

```
grep "$SHELL"'$' foo
grep "$SHELL\$" foo
```